# Python librosa error "Audio buffer is not Fortran-contiguous"

Tags: python, numpy, audio, librosa

I am using `librosa`

Just `load` and `stft`, I hit the error `Audio buffer is not Fortran-contiguous`

I googled around and found I need to add `np.asfortranarray`,So I add these sentences but in vain.

```
a, sr = librosa.load("mywave.wav",sr=self.sr,mono=False)

print(a.shape) #(2, 151199)

a[0] = np.asfortranarray(a[0])# try to avoide Fortran-contiguous
a[1] = np.asfortranarray(a[1])

# but this returns error
#Audio buffer is not Fortran-contiguous. Use numpy.asfortranarray to ensure Fortran contiguity.    

stft_L = librosa.stft(a[0], n_fft=self.stft_frame,hop_length= self.hop_frame, window='hann')
```

At first time I made this code, (maybe half a year ago), it worked.

Is there any solution??

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding what C- vs Fortran-contiguous memory layout is, and what that means you can do and can't do. For example, changing the memory layout of a line in an array

```
a[0] = np.asfortranarray(a[0])
```

makes no sense, as the memory layout dictates *what a line is*.

To illustrate that a little bit, lets have a look at some Fortran-contiguous data

```
x = np.asfortranarray(np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4))
x.flags.f_contiguous
# True

x
# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
#        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Internally, that 2D array is of course saved linearly, and the C-/Fortran-contigouity dictates whether lines or columns come first:

```
x.flatten('A')
# array([ 0,  4,  8,  1,  5,  9,  2,  6, 10,  3,  7, 11])

np.asfortranarray(x).flatten('A')
# array([ 0,  4,  8,  1,  5,  9,  2,  6, 10,  3,  7, 11])

np.ascontiguousarray(x).flatten('A')
# array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
```

Fortran-memory layout is column-first, i.e. columns stay together in memory. C-memory is row-first, i.e. rows stay together in memory.

What can be really confusing is the fact that views in that array can be contiguous, or not:

```
x.flags.f_contiguous, x[0].flags.f_contiguous
# (True, False)
```

`x` is obviously contiguous, but `x[0]` is not. That is because `[0, 1, 2, 3]` are not next to each other in memory.

What you tried to do

```
a = x.copy('A')

a.flags.f_contiguous, a[0].flags.f_contiguous
# (True, False)

a[0] = np.asfortranarray(a[0])
a[1] = np.asfortranarray(a[1])

a.flags.f_contiguous, a[0].flags.f_contiguous
# (True, False)
```

will not work, because changing the layout of a single line makes no sense.

Now here comes the confusing part: If you have a Fortran-contiguous array and you want the first line to be Fortran-contiguous, you can't change the array to be Fortran-contiguous:

```
a = x.copy('A')

a = np.asfortranarray(a)
a.flags.f_contiguous, a[0].flags.f_contiguous
# (True, False)
```

because columns are contiguous, but not rows.

If instead you change the array to be C-contigous

```
a = x.copy('A')

a = np.ascontiguousarray(a)
a.flags.f_contiguous, a[0].flags.f_contiguous
# (False, True)
```

which means rows are now contiguous.

Another solution is to simply take a copy of the data

```
a = x.copy('A')

a[0].copy().flags.f_contiguous
# True
```

as taking a copy will write the data into a new, linear, and contiguous array.

So the final solution?

```
a, sr = librosa.load("mywave.wav")
stft_L = librosa.stft(a[0].copy())
```

But librosa also [removed the need for contiguity recently](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/pull/1140/files), so this problem should slowly disappear in the future.